# puppeteer iFrame - TypeError: Cannot read property 'move' of undefined

Tags: javascript, iframe, puppeteer

I'm trying to solve a captcha in an iframe. Am I accessing iframe correctly with the codes below? I'm able to click the button in the iframe but not move the mouse. I'm getting x,y, width, height positions but the positions may be wrong since it's in an iframe. If I grab the iframe URL, visit it and solve the captcha then I'm able to move the mouse and solve the captcha.

Thanks

```html
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const fs = require('fs').promises
const Jimp = require('jimp')
const pixelmatch = require('pixelmatch')
const { cv } = require('opencv-wasm')

async function findPuzzlePosition (page) {
    let images = await page.$$eval('.geetest_canvas_img canvas', canvases => canvases.map(canvas => canvas.toDataURL().replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, '')))

    await fs.writeFile(`./puzzle.png`, images[1], 'base64')

    let srcPuzzleImage = await Jimp.read('./puzzle.png')
    let srcPuzzle = cv.matFromImageData(srcPuzzleImage.bitmap)
    let dstPuzzle = new cv.Mat()

    cv.cvtColor(srcPuzzle, srcPuzzle, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv.threshold(srcPuzzle, dstPuzzle, 127, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)

    let kernel = cv.Mat.ones(5, 5, cv.CV_8UC1)
    let anchor = new cv.Point(-1, -1)
    cv.dilate(dstPuzzle, dstPuzzle, kernel, anchor, 1)
    cv.erode(dstPuzzle, dstPuzzle, kernel, anchor, 1)

    let contours = new cv.MatVector()
    let hierarchy = new cv.Mat()
    cv.findContours(dstPuzzle, contours, hierarchy, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    let contour = contours.get(0)
    let moment = cv.moments(contour)

    return [Math.floor(moment.m10 / moment.m00), Math.floor(moment.m01 / moment.m00)]
}

async function findDiffPosition (page) {
    await page.waitFor(100)

    let srcImage = await Jimp.read('./diff.png')
    let src = cv.matFromImageData(srcImage.bitmap)

    let dst = new cv.Mat()
    let kernel = cv.Mat.ones(5, 5, cv.CV_8UC1)
    let anchor = new cv.Point(-1, -1)

    cv.threshold(src, dst, 127, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)
    cv.erode(dst, dst, kernel, anchor, 1)
    cv.dilate(dst, dst, kernel, anchor, 1)
    cv.erode(dst, dst, kernel, anchor, 1)
    cv.dilate(dst, dst, kernel, anchor, 1)

    cv.cvtColor(dst, dst, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv.threshold(dst, dst, 150, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

    let contours = new cv.MatVector()
    let hierarchy = new cv.Mat()
    cv.findContours(dst, contours, hierarchy, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    let contour = contours.get(0)
    let moment = cv.moments(contour)

    return [Math.floor(moment.m10 / moment.m00), Math.floor(moment.m01 / moment.m00)]
}

async function saveSliderCaptchaImages(page) {

    await page.waitForSelector('[aria-label="Click to verify"]')
    await page.waitFor(3000)

    await page.click('[aria-label="Click to verify"]')

    await page.waitForSelector('.geetest_canvas_img canvas', { visible: true })
    await page.waitFor(1000)
    let images = await page.$$eval('.geetest_canvas_img canvas', canvases => {
        return canvases.map(canvas => canvas.toDataURL().replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, ''))
    })

    await fs.writeFile(`./captcha.png`, images[0], 'base64')
    await fs.writeFile(`./original.png`, images[2], 'base64')
}

async function saveDiffImage() {
    const originalImage = await Jimp.read('./original.png')
    const captchaImage = await Jimp.read('./captcha.png')

    const { width, height } = originalImage.bitmap
    const diffImage = new Jimp(width, height)

    const diffOptions = { includeAA: true, threshold: 0.2 }

    pixelmatch(originalImage.bitmap.data, captchaImage.bitmap.data, diffImage.bitmap.data, width, height, diffOptions)
    diffImage.write('./diff.png')
}


async function solveCaptcha (page) {
    console.log(page)
    await saveSliderCaptchaImages(page)
    await saveDiffImage()

    let [cx, cy] = await findDiffPosition(page)

    const sliderHandle = await page.$('.geetest_slider_button')
    const handle = await sliderHandle.boundingBox()
    await page.waitFor(5000)
    console.log(handle)
    let xPosition = handle.x + handle.width / 2
    let yPosition = handle.y + handle.height / 2
    await page.mouse.move(xPosition, yPosition)
    await page.mouse.down()

    xPosition = handle.x + cx - handle.width / 2
    yPosition = handle.y + handle.height / 3
    await page.mouse.move(xPosition, yPosition, { steps: 25 })

    await page.waitFor(100)

    let [cxPuzzle, cyPuzzle] = await findPuzzlePosition(page)

    xPosition = xPosition + cx - cxPuzzle
    yPosition = handle.y + handle.height / 2
    await page.mouse.move(xPosition, yPosition, { steps: 5 })
    await page.mouse.up()

    await page.waitFor(3000)
    // success!

    await fs.unlink('./original.png')
    await fs.unlink('./captcha.png')
    await fs.unlink('./diff.png')
    await fs.unlink('./puzzle.png')

}


async function start(){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        defaultViewport: { width: 1366, height: 768 },
        args: [ '--proxy-server=x.x.x.x:xxx', '--disable-web-security',
        '--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process'],

    })
   
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.authenticate({
        username: 'xxx',
        password: 'xxx',
        });

  
    await page.goto('https://someurlwithcaptchainiframe.com', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' })
    await page.waitFor(1000)
    await page.content();

    try {
    innerText = await page.evaluate(() =>  {
        return JSON.parse(document.querySelector("body").innerText); 
    }); 
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log('BLOCKED, we want to solve captcha here..')
        await page.waitFor(9000)
        //frame = await page.mainFrame().childFrames()
        //solveCaptcha(frame)
        let captchaFrame // this will be populated later by our identified frame

        for (const frame of page.mainFrame().childFrames()){
            // Here you can use few identifying methods like url(),name(),title()
            if (frame.url().includes('geo')){
                console.log('we found the captcha iframe')
                captchaFrame = frame
                console.log('Frame URL: '+captchaFrame._url)
                await solveCaptcha(captchaFrame)
        
                
                
                // we assign this frame to myFrame to use it later
            }
        }

        console.log('HERE..')
        await page.waitFor(90000)
        



       // solveCaptcha(frame)
    }

    //console.log("innerText now contains the JSON");
    //console.log(innerText);
    


}
start()
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to:
improve content quality, improve code formatting, include error message, include screenshots.
See [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You must use ".mouse" object from page instance, not from iframe, like this

```
        if(await page.$('div[id="px-captcha"] > div > iframe[style*="khtml-user-select: none"]') != null){
            const frameHandle = await page.$('div[id="px-captcha"] > div > iframe[style*="khtml-user-select: none"]')
            const captcha_frame = await frameHandle.contentFrame()   


            if(await captcha_frame.$('div[aria-label*="Human Challenge"]') != null){
                const example = await captcha_frame.$('div[aria-label*="Human Challenge"]') 
                const box = await example.boundingBox()  

                await page.mouse.move(box.x + box.width / 2, box.y + box.height / 2) 
                await page.mouse.down()
                await page.waitForTimeout(5000)
                await page.mouse.up()

            
            } 
        }
```